# I want to generate an email report (email sent copy) as soon as the email sent to the user in Laravel using Mail function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail, laravel-events

I want to generate an email report (email sent copy) as soon as the email sent to the user in Laravel using the Mail function 
below is the sample image for sent email

[please find the attached sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/537WB.png)

Comment: Hi & welcome to the SO. Please read this first [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I used the below code to send the email

Mail::to($request->input('test_email'))->send(new TestEmail($emailTemplate->content, $emailTemplate->subject));

and Created EventServiceProvider to log the same.

protected $listen = [
        'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
            'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
        ]

In LogSentMessage: 

EmailLog::create([
                'name' => $mailEvent->message->template_name,
                'user_id' => $mailEvent->message->user_id,
                'email_template_id' => $mailEvent->message->template_id,
            ]);

Answer (score 0):

you can send same mail using  `bcc` **Blind Carbon Copy** like this way :

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->bcc('secret mail')
    ->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```

so you can get exact copy of mail send to user , and bcc information is not visible to user.

Comment: Thanks for responding Saurabh, 

Is there is any way to get the report(sent email) on pdf as I am receiving an email if I used Bcc

I want to store in our application and save the report into the database as well.